# How to use my React components as a shared component library through NPM?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a shared ui component library. I just started a new `create-react-app` and deleted all the things I didn't need. In my index.js file, I have this:

```
import Button from "./src/components/Button";

export default {
  Button,
};
```

Button is just a dummy component I have made to test the workflow.

```
import React from "react";

const Button = () => {
  return <h1>BUTTON</h1>;
};

export default Button;
```

In my frontend app, using `npm link`, I have created a symlink to this shared ui component library. However, when I try to load it, it throws an error:

```
../myapp-client/src/components/Button.js
SyntaxError: /Users/edmundmai/Documents/src/myapp/myapp-ui/src/components/Button.js: Unexpected token (4:9)

      2 | 
      3 | const Button = () => {
    > 4 |   return <h1>BUTTON</h1>;
        |          ^
      5 | };
      6 | 
      7 | export default Button;
```

What tool am I missing so that I can export the `Button` from my shared ui library? I'm guessing I need to build the app instead of just serving up the `src` folder, but I'm not sure what that tool is exactly. Is it babel?

Comment: "making your compiler JSX aware". The error is that you're giving plain JS context a `<` (note the position of the caret in that error) so you'll need to at the very least do some kind of webpack/babel pass on it.

Comment: Makes sense. So instead of using `create-react-app`, which assumes I'm building a webpage using index.html, is there another command I can run to compile my shared ui component library app?

Comment: It... doesn't? `create-react-app` exists specifically for developing a React application, but your button code is likely simply not getting babel-converted because it's buried as a dependency. You'll have to generate the real `.js` version and import that, or instead of using an `npm link`, you'll have to use a real symlink so that it's considered "local files" for bundling, rather than a dependency for which the assumption is made that it has already been properly transpiled.

Comment: When I run `react-scripts build` it does break because it expects an index.html file.